# Exception in morphia-0.93-SNAPSHOT.jar

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to mapp pojo  class to mongodb using morphia-0.93-SNAPSHOT.jar but it is throwing exception that **"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bson/types/CodeWScope"** which is bson's exception.So I am not able to run those programs.So please can anybody help me to solved this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I got the solution of my problem.I made the changes in morphia code and generate error free jar.If anyone want it then [click here](https://code.google.com/p/morphia-modified-jar/) .On this link by clicking on source-browse you can get it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using mongodb java driver 2.0? Might want to check your dependencies.

http://code.google.com/p/morphia/wiki/Dependencies